# Isar: Is there a way to do a text search on the items of an IsarLinks object using indexes?

Tags: flutter, text-search, flutter-isar

I have a collection of `Bar`s, each of which have isar links to `Foo`s:

```
@collection
class Bar{
  Id? id;
  
  final foos = IsarLinks<Foo>();
  ... // Bar stuff
};
```

Each `Foo` object has a field named `text`, which is a `String`:

```
@collection
class Foo{
  Id? id;
  
  late String text;
  ... // Foo stuff
};
```

Now, what I would like to do is search and find all the `Foo`s linked to a particular `Bar` that contain all of the given key words in their `text` (preferably case insensitive). So, searching with the key words "canada" and "street" should match a `Foo` with `text = "I don't know what street, Canada is on. - Al Capone`

Isar has a guide on [how to do a full text search](https://isar.dev/recipes/full_text_search.html#full-text-search). In it, they recommend adding an index of the words of the text searched on, like so:

```
@collection
class Foo{
  Id? id;
  
  late String text;
  
  @Index(type: IndexType.value, caseSensitive: false) // for more flexibility; see https://isar.dev/recipes/full_text_search.html#i-want-more-control
  List<String> get words => Isar.splitWords(text); // see https://isar.dev/recipes/full_text_search.html#splitting-text-the-right-way
};
```

However, there does not seem to be an easy way to filer based on an index with `IsarLinks`.

My questions:

- Is there a way to filter based on an index through all the items of an `IsarLinks` object?
- If not, what would be the best way to perform a text search like I described? As a bonus question, why can't I do this with `IsarLinks`?

Note: I know I can simply use `IsarLinks.filter` and build a query that selects all `Foo`s with `text` containing all the key words, but I am wondering if there is a way to do a text search in the way `Isar` (with indexes) recommends on `IsarLinks`.

Answer (score 1):

Isar does not provide a direct way to filter based on an index through all the items of an `IsarLinks` object. The indexing functionality is primarily designed for individual properties of an object rather than for complex relationships like `IsarLinks`.

To perform a text search across the linked `Foo` objects based on the `text` field, you can follow these steps:

1. Retrieve the linked `Foo` objects from the `IsarLinks` of a specific `Bar`.
2. Filter the `Foo` objects based on the search keywords using the `where` method and a custom condition.
3. Use a case-insensitive search condition to match the keywords in the `text` field.

Here's an example implementation of the text search functionality:

```dart
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

@Collection()
class Bar {
  @Id()
  int? id;

  final foos = IsarLinks<Foo>();

  // ... Bar stuff
}

@Collection()
class Foo {
  @Id()
  int? id;

  late String text;

  // ... Foo stuff
}

void searchTextInFoos(Bar bar, List<String> keywords) {
  final foos = bar.foos;

  final searchResults = foos
      .where((foo) => keywords.every(
            (keyword) => foo.text.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase()),
          ))
      .toList();

  // Use the searchResults as needed
}
```

In this example, the `searchTextInFoos` function takes a `Bar` object and a list of search `keywords` as input. It filters the `Foo` objects linked to that `Bar` based on the keywords using the `where` method.

The `where` method applies a custom condition to each `Foo` object, checking if all keywords are contained within the `text` field. The condition uses a case-insensitive comparison by converting both the `text` and `keyword` to lowercase.

Finally, the search results are stored in the `searchResults` list, which you can utilize as needed.

While it would be convenient to perform a full-text search directly on an `IsarLinks` object with the help of indexing, the current version of Isar does not provide this capability. However, the approach outlined above allows you to achieve the desired text search functionality for the linked `Foo` objects.